# Create checkbox list in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'd like to create a form which contains a text field and a list of checkboxes.

Using the underscore template function with a [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) statement I can get it rendered.

When I click the save button I get the model (with the text field) but the array for the checkboxes is not where it should be....

This my view model:

```
window.SpotEditView= Marionette.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var featureList = ['Rail', 'Curb','Pipe'];
        //this.el = this.compiledTemplate(this.model.toJSON());
        var viewModel = this.model.toJSON();
        viewModel.features = featureList;

        $(this.el).html( _.template(htmlBody, viewModel));
        return;
    },

    render: function () {
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "change"        : "change",
        "click .save"   : "beforeSave",
        "click .delete" : "delete",
        "drop #picture" : "dropHandler"
    },

    beforeSave: function () {
        var self = this;
        var check = this.model.validateAll();
        if (check.isValid === false) {
            utils.displayValidationErrors(check.messages);
            return false;
        }
        // Upload picture file if a new file was dropped in the drop area
        if (this.pictureFile) {
            this.model.set("picture", this.pictureFile.name);
            utils.uploadFile(this.pictureFile,
                function () {
                    self.save();
                }
            );
        } else {
            self.save();
        }
        return false;
    },

    save: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function (model) {
                self.render();
                var point = model.toMarker();
                app.mapView.model.markers.add(point);
                app.navigate('map', true);
                app.mapView.openInfo(point);

            },
            error: function () {
                utils.showAlert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying to save this item', 'alert-error');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the relevant part of my html template:

```
<% _.each(features, function(f,key) { %>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="features[<%= key-1 %>]" value="<%= f %>">
    <%= f %>
</label>
<% }); %>
```

The model that the save function recieves looks like this:

```
{..
    attributes:{ ...
        features:[],
        features[1]:'Dick',
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems as if the backbone 'form-parser' cannot handle the array.

Is there a fix or a better solution to this approach?

Comment: What model do you expect to receive? And can you post the form-parser section of your code?

Comment: I'm expecting to have my view model updated. Regarding the form-parser. There's no magic from my side, just the normal Backbone functionality. I've added my view model in the question. See the beforeSave method.